# Flot JS Line Chart Order by different property

Tags: javascript, arrays, flot

I have an Array like this:

["Week 1, Year 2014", 3, { full_date: "Sun Apr 06 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)"}]

[image]

The problem I am having is that the dates are not ordering correctly, I have five different line charts, each with different dates appearing on them. But the line chart is adding them together and not inserting them inbetween, so if my first array has Week 1, Week 3 and Week 4 and my second array has Week 1, Week 2 and Week 4, it will come out like

Week 1, Week 3, Week 4, Week 2 and not order them. My solution was the create a filler array which has all the options from all the arrays, so an invisible line but with every date, but I was wondering if there was an option to make it do this by itself or if possible sort by a different property, e.g. the full_date.

```
var options = {
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true
        },
        points: {
            radius: 3,
            fill: true,
            show: true
        }
    },
    xaxis: {

        tickLength: 0,
        mode: "categories",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'open sans',
        axisLabelPadding: 10
    },
    yaxes: [{
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'open sans',
        axisLabelPadding: 3,

    }, {
        position: "right",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'open sans',
        axisLabelPadding: 3
    }
    ], legend: {
        noColumns: 1,
        labelBoxBorderColor: "#000000",
        position: "nw"
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: "#633200",
        backgroundColor: { colors: ["#ffffff", "#EDF5FF"] }
    },
    colors: ["#FF0000", "#0022FF"]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no simpler option in flot itself.

Creating the filler array with all weeks or extending the existing arrays with empty values for the missing weeks are the best options. Depending on your server-side code one or the other may be easier.